# Passing a piped variable to a sub-command called within GNU parallel

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, gnu-parallel

In `bash`, I am trying to find a list of files and pipe them to `parallel`.

```
find *.fasta | parallel "Gblocks {} -b2=$(( "$(cat {} | grep \> | wc -l)" / 2 + 1 ))"
```

Where `Gblocks` is a single-threaded executable, and the flag `-b2` sets a variable that is based on the number of `>` characters in the referenced file.

My problem is that `cat {}` doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I know why it doesn't work: the `{}` function is part of `parallel`, and I'm trying to reference it within a command *within* the parallel command. I just have no idea how to actually get this to function.

If the first file from `find` is `myfile.fasta`, then the command should look like:

```
find *.fasta | parallel "Gblocks myfile.fasta -b2=$(( "$(cat myfile.fasta | grep \> | wc -l)" / 2 + 1 ))"
```

Edit: As @KamilMaciorowski suggested, I needed to change the first set of double quotes to single quotes, thus:

```
find *.fasta | parallel 'Gblocks {} -b2=$(( "$(cat {} | grep \> | wc -l)" / 2 + 1 ))'
```

Comment: No time to test, so just a comment: your `$(( … ))` is double-quoted *in the current shell*, so it gets expanded by the current shell. You probably want to single-quote the shell code you want `parallel` to run. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That did it! I don't have a solid understanding of how double and single quotes work in bash; looks like I have some reading to do. Much appreciated!